# Object Required Error in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am creating LineChart in a userform by reading the guide from this website
http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip66.htm

```
Dim ChartNum As Integer
Dim CurrentChart As String
Dim Fname As String


Private Sub UpdateChart()
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    CurrentChart.Parent.width = 300
    CurrentChart.Parent.height = 150

'   Save chart as GIF
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export FileName:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"


    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
End Sub
```

I also have assign the 3 variables at top. I have the data for the chart in "Sheet1" and the Chart in the "Charts" sheet. But now i'm stuck to update the chart. When i click the Commandbutton to update the chart, it says like this

```
Compile Error : Object Required
```

And the error points to the CurrentChart

```
 Set CurrentChart = Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart
```

I expect to update the chart everytime the user clicks the command button.
Any idea how to solve this? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `Dim CurrentChart As Object`

Comment: @Comintern Yes, thank you so much. That solves the problem. But now i have new problem, i cannot select new chart to update. i want to change the row and column.

Comment: @Comintern Maybe there should be a selection of X axis, Yaxis and the title for the chart.